# Adding Memoization - Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am currently practicing some dynamic programming and I came across the *Circus Tower* problem.
I solved the problem with dynamic programming and implemented it using recursion.  I've tested it with few inputs and it seems to work fine.

Now, I've been struggling few hours trying to figure out how to add memoization to my solution.

**Questions**

1. How can I add a working memoization to my solution. Where is my mistake in this case?
2. Is there any rule of thumb, or guidlines for how to add memoizations in general.

---

**The Circus Tower Problem:**
A circus is designing a tower of people standing atop one another’s shoulders. Each person must be both shorter and lighter than the person below him. Given the heights and weights of each person in the circus, write a method to compute the largest possible number of people in such a tower.

**My Solution & Code**
Dynamic Programming

```
OPT[N,P] = highest tower with N given persons and person P is at the top
----------------------------------------------------------
OPT[0,P]                                = 0
OPT[i,P] where person i can be above P  = max(OPT[i-1,i]+1,OPT[i-1,P])
OPT[i,P] else                           = OPT[i-1,P]
```

Code:

```
struct Person{
    int ht;
    int wt;
};

// Without Memoization
int circusTower(int n, Person* top, std::vector<Person>& persons){
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    if (top == NULL || top->ht > persons[n - 1].ht && top->wt > persons[n - 1].wt)
        return max(circusTower(n - 1, &persons[n - 1], persons) + 1, circusTower(n - 1, top, persons));
    else
        return circusTower(n - 1, top, persons);
}

// With Memoization
int circusTower(int n, Person* top, std::vector<Person>& persons, std::vector<int>& memo){
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    int result;
    if (memo[n-1] == 0) {
        if (top == NULL || top->ht > persons[n - 1].ht && top->wt > persons[n - 1].wt)
            result = max(circusTower(n - 1, &persons[n - 1], persons, memo) + 1,
                         circusTower(n - 1, top, persons, memo));
        else
            result = circusTower(n - 1, top, persons, memo);

        memo[n - 1] = result;
        return result;
    } else {
        return memo[n-1];
    }
}
```

Main - test:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<Person> persons = { {65, 100},{100, 150},{56, 90}, {75, 190}, {60, 95},{68, 110} };
    std::stable_sort(persons.begin(), persons.end(), sortByWt);
    std::stable_sort(persons.begin(), persons.end(), sortByHt);

    std::vector<int> memo(6,0);

    //Without memoization
    cout << circusTower(6, NULL, persons) << endl;
    //With memoization
    cout << circusTower(6, NULL, persons, memo) << endl;
}
```

In the example inside the main above, the right result is 5. My regular solution (without memoization) prints 5, but with memoization it prints 6.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is to use your debugger, but not to ask at Stack Overflow before you did so. Tell us all your observations you made when inspecting your code stepping through line by line in 1st place. Also you might want to read **[How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**  At least leave us with a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem. (This is a personal stock comment provided by πάντα ῥεῖ™)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did, I understand that what I am doing is wrong, I just cannot figure out how to make it right. Of course, I am not asking to debug my code but maybe to give some guidance for how to add memoization.

Comment: In the memoization case, `if (memo[n-1] == 0)` there's no return.

Comment: If the downvoters could explain what is the problem with my question that would be great. I am not asking anybody to debug my code, I gave this code just so there will be some reference to how I tried implementing this. And still, I am looking for a right way to implement memoization, not only in this particular case but also in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method depend of 3 arguments
but you memoize only from the first argument `n`

Indeed in your case, the third one (`persons`) is constant,
but the second one (`top`) changes during the recursive call.

so due to your memoization, both the following return wrongly the same value:

- `circusTower(n - 1, &persons[n - 1], persons, memo)`
- `circusTower(n - 1, top, persons, memo)`

Comment: Thanks! So if I get this right - in this case, in order to memoize I need to use a 2d array? (or somekind of hash table with pair of `n` and `top` as key)?   Can I generalize from this that in every such kind of problem I need to check whether or not my arguments are changing in each recursive call and from this to build my memoization?

Comment: @A.Sarid: In ideal a 3D "array" for each argument. If you create a class to bound memo with *constant* argument as `Persons`, you may stick to 2D *array*.